# A working MGTwitterEngine iPhone example project

Tags: iphone, ios, oauth, mgtwitterengine

I'm trying to find a working version of the an up-to-date MGTwitterEngine iPhone project. The example app included with MGTwitterEngine is a Mac app which I can't get to compile, apparently due to multiple missing dependencies. (each time I try to resolve a compile error I just get even more errors...)

Is there a working example out there? Just a shell which lets you log in to twitter. (and which uses oauth, not xauth - which is deprecated).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original source code is located on [github](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine). It looks like the last time it was updated was in September of 2010. I am not aware of any other updates as of recently. The original source is probably going to be your best choice.

Alternatively, there are many other Twitter libraries  you can use.

[Twitter+OAuth](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone)

Comment: this was useful - http://icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/

Comment: Why the downvote? Care to explain rather than snipe reputation?

Comment: @cannyboy not saying it was you in particular, but someone did who decided not to back the downvote and explain why they feel the need to downvote a chosen answer.